# Одинаковые слова в тексте. Преобразовать программу

Tags: java

Программа по поиску одинаковых слов в текста написано, нужно создать отдельные классы для текста, предложения и букв. Знаю, как разделить текст на массив предложений, предложения на слова+знаки пунктуации, слова на буквы.
Но как дописать необходимые классы в основную программу?

```
import java.util.*;
public class text2 {

     private static final String TEXT = "слово1 слово2 слово3.слово2.слово4 слово1!";

     private static final String[] WORDS_TO_SEARCH = TEXT.split("[ .,!]");


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            final List<Set<String>> sentencesByWords = new ArrayList<>();
            for (final String sentence : TEXT.split("[ .!?]\\s*")) {
                sentencesByWords.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(sentence.split("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+"))));
            }

            final Set<String> wordsToSearch = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(WORDS_TO_SEARCH));

            final Map<String, Integer> counter = new HashMap<>();
            for (final String wordToSearch : wordsToSearch) {
                if (!counter.containsKey(wordToSearch)) {
                    counter.put(wordToSearch, 0);
                }
                for (final Set<String> sentence : sentencesByWords) {
                    if (sentence.contains(wordToSearch)) {
                        counter.put(wordToSearch, counter.get(wordToSearch) + 1);
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println(counter);
        }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyText
{
    ArrayList<Sentense> sentences = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyText(ArrayList<Sentense> sentences)
    {
       this.sentences.addAll(sentences);
    }

    public ArrayList<Sentense> getSentences()
    {
       return this.sentences;
    }
}

public class Sentense
{
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

    public Sentense(ArrayList<String> words)
    {
       this.words.addAll(words);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getWords()
    {
       return this.words;
    }
}
```

Comment: @sunday, ну... Вместо строковых представлений используйте предложенное... Мне сложно дать прямые рекомендации глобальная цель программы неизвестна. Вы в любом случае можете по аналогии сделать как угодно)